# pandas dataframe resample sum daily entries only for complete months

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframes with daily entries that can start and end not on months' boundaries. I want to sum by month but without the first months entries if they don't start at the first day of the month and the last months entries if they don't end at the last day of the month.

```
             gas
2022-10-18  1.81
2022-10-19  2.69
2022-10-20  3.06
2022-10-21  3.10
2022-10-22  2.28
...          ...
2024-02-03  5.68
2024-02-04  5.83
2024-02-05  5.74
2024-02-06  6.55
2024-02-07  3.17
```

So far I do the sum using `df.resample('MS').sum()`. But with this I get also partial months' sums:

```
2022-10-01   34.040
2022-11-01  164.825
2022-12-01  236.335
2023-01-01  226.180
2023-02-01  197.230
...             ...
2023-10-01   78.060
2023-11-01  191.590
2023-12-01  219.650
2024-01-01  252.370
2024-02-01   38.625
```

Note: All the other daily entries in the middle of the dataframes exist by having used interpolation when aggregating the daily dataframes. So probably counting the number of daily entries for a month and comparing that to the number of days in the month would be a way, but how would that be used as a filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data = {'gas': np.random.randint(0, 10, 60)},
    index = pd.date_range('20220118', periods=60, freq='D')
)

res = df.resample('MS').agg(["size", "sum"])
res.columns = ["days", "gas"]
res = (res[res.index.days_in_month == res.days]).drop(columns=["days"])

---------------
            gas
2022-02-01  109
```